Copy and rename batch file
1folder (cover.jpg)
2folder (cover.jpg)
3folder (cover.jpg)
.
.

There are so many jpg file with same name cover.jpg in multiple folders.
I am trying to copy and rename all cover.jpg in another folder with names like 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg.....
How can I do this using batch ?  (Windows)
I tried
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "files=F:\rsack\다이나믹 듀오\*.jpg"
set "destDir=F:\rsack\다이나믹 듀오"

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir "%files%" /b /s') do (
  for %%d in ("%destDir%\%%~nf*") do (
    set /a count+=1
  )
  xcopy "%%f" "%destDir%\%%~nf!count!%%~xf*"
  set count=
)

and
for /F "delims=" %f in ('dir "F:\rsack\?ㅼ씠?섎? ???*.jpg" /b /s') do (
for %d in ("F:\rsack\?ㅼ씠?섎? ???\%~nf*") do (set /a count+=1 )
 xcopy "%f" "F:\rsack\?ㅼ씠?섎? ???\%~nf!count!%~xf*"
 set count=
)

can't find file.

Yea,..i wondered the same, why batch? powershell is soo much more neat ^^ -@harrymc ,what do yu mean where hes stuck, he has idea, and thats where we are :D

I got spare time :D

Save this as RenameThemAll.ps1 and save anywhere on pc(i guess, didnt rly test), then paste whole code in that file, save, right click and Run with PowerShell...
-This will ask you what directory you want to check, and it will go trough all subdirectories
-It will ask you to provide file name for name example
-It will try to keep extensions as they were if same name files with different extension exist
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$folderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
$folderBrowser.Description = "Select Directory"
$folderBrowser.RootFolder = "Desktop"
$folderBrowser.ShowNewFolderButton = $false
$dialogResult = $folderBrowser.ShowDialog()

if ($dialogResult -ne [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    Write-Output "Folder selection canceled."
    exit
}
$selectedDirectory = $folderBrowser.SelectedPath
$fileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$fileDialog.Title = "Select File to Rename"
$fileDialog.InitialDirectory = $selectedDirectory
$fileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*"
$fileDialog.Multiselect = $false
$dialogResult = $fileDialog.ShowDialog()

if ($dialogResult -ne [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
    Write-Output "File selection canceled."
    exit
}
$selectedFile = $fileDialog.FileName
$baseName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($selectedFile)
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $selectedDirectory -Recurse -File
$index = 1

foreach ($file in $files) {
    if ($file.BaseName -eq $baseName) {
        $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file)
        $newName = "$baseName" + "_$index" + $extension
        $file | Rename-Item -NewName $newName
        $index++
    }
}

